# AlertDialog is showing fullscreen for some reason

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, androidx

I build and show standart simple AlertDialog from pressing button in navigation drawer, with context of Activity, for unknown reason it shows fullscreen, but I need standart dialog in center.

Here is my code (The same code works as expected in other activities of my app):

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(mainActivity)
    .setTitle(mainActivity.getString(R.string.attention))
    .setPositiveButton(mainActivity.getString(R.string.exit), (dialog, which) -> {
        dialog.dismiss();
        mainActivity.finish();
    })
    .setNegativeButton(mainActivity.getString(R.string.cancel), (dialog, which) -> {
        dialog.dismiss();
    })
    .setMessage(mainActivity.getString(R.string.warnLogout))
    .create()
    .show();
```

Comment: The dialogue layout depend on the theme you choose for the Application, probably you have choose a FullScreen theme.

Comment: no, there is no FullScreen theme

Comment: Have you applied some style in your theme? Can you show your `styles`?

Comment: Yes, but same code works nice in other activity with same style

Comment: Passing wrong context can create problems. Are you sure you are passing the current one?

Comment: Yes, I double checked context is right one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in wrong import: I have migrated recently project to AndroidX, and when I wrote AlertDialog logic, mistakenly chose legacy import. It appears that no errors and no warnings been shown, and buttons worked as expected, but it appeared as wrong Fullscreen layout dialog in my case:

WRONG:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
```

RIGHT:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code for alert dialog.

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Alert")
                .setMessage("Hello This is Alert Dialog.")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        }).show();
```

Output :
[image]

Comment: It doesn't change anything

Comment: This is simple logic it should work please try in other activity.

Comment: Like I said, Faldu, it works as expected in other activities